# DNS records: Remote A record for website and local server for mail server

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dns-zone, cpanel, whm

First of all. I'm sorry if my question is irrelevant, bacuse i'm new on DNS Records.

I have 2 Server, will call them #Server-1 and #Server-2.

For. eg. i have a web site with domain name `www.example.com`. Mail and Website running at `#Server-1.`

Question:

- How can i change only web site to point `#Server-2` and mail server will work on `#Server-1`?

Website's DNS records are as below;

`A Record: example.com -> #Server-1- IP`

`MX Record: example.com -> Prio:0 -> example.com.`

`CNAME Record: mail -> example.com.`

`NS1 Record: example.com -> ns1.#Server1.com`

`NS2 Record: example.com -> ns2.#Server1.com`

So how can i point only web to `#Server-2`. I have no access to `#Server-2`

Any help greatly appricated.
P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a new DNS entry, since right now since mail/web are shared on Server1. After that's complete, set the MX to the mail host & update the top-level to point to Server2.

Something like this:

```
example.com. IN A 10.0.0.101
mail.example.com. IN A 10.0.0.100
example.com. IN MX 0 mail.example.com.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.